# Flushing PutSFTP flowfile results?

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to store results into SFTP, these results are generated from large SQL dump between date ranges. For the same, I am running it over a loop for the date lists.

But the problem lies in during iteration `i++`. The flowfile content keeps growing from the PutSFTP's outgoing flowfile content.

How can I flush the flowfile results of `PutSFTP` processor so that it can be avoided for next iteration? However, at the same time, I would like to maintain the other important variables from different `UpdateAttribute` within the loop.

The given Nifi flow can be shown as follows.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use ***ModifyBytes*** processor,After **PutSFTP** processor.

**Configs:**

[image]

With this configs we are going to **remove all contents** of the existing `flowfile` and this processor **won't delete any existing attributes** associated with the flowfile.

**Flow:**

```
  -> other processors
 |(success)
  -> PutSFTP
 |(success)
  -> ModifyBytes
 |(success)
  -> i++(UpdateAttribute)
 |(success)
  -> other processors
```